# Eclipse - Reference to undefined variable jrebel_args

Tags: eclipse, jrebel, eclipse-kepler

After uninstalling JRebel from Eclipse Kepler (on Ubuntu 12.04), when I try to run my web app on server I get the following error:

'Starting Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.
Reference to undefined variable jrebel_args.

How can I remove this reference?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Double click the server, click on `Open launch configuration` link; in the Arguments tab, under VM arguments, it has a `${jrebel_args}` variable defined there. Remove it.

Comment: Winner. For future reference, the Launch Configuration in Eclipse Kepler is under Run -> Run Configurations.

Comment: Double click server in Server's Tab. Choose open launch configuration. Remove ${jrebel_args:org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXType/Java SE 7 [1.7.0_67]} or what not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I still wasn't able to open the `Open launch configuration` menu, so I had to remove the server and add it again to eclipse. Now everything is fine again.